# Chrome Android: Music website stops working in the background

Tags: android, google-chrome, spotify, media

I play Jiosaavn, Gaana, Spotify background in Chrome. After playing 2-3 songs it stops.
Chrome is not really force stopped but only website media stopped.
If anyone knows how to resolve this please help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about an issue with Chrome

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question does not meet the guidelines of Stack Overflow. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help to understand which types of questions should be asked in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

One tab on chrome takes about 100MB memory So Playing Spotify, jiosaavn in chrome background playback stopped if 100mb memory. Just close the tab open new one play the songs. Link [https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16560747![enter](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16560747!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuPo1.png)